# Trigger a compiler error when trying to add char* to int?

Tags: c++

C++ compilers happily compiles this code, with no warning:

```
int ival = 8;
const char *strval = "x";
const char *badresult = ival + strval;
```

Here we add a char* pointer value (*strval*) to an int value (*ival*) and store the result in a char* pointer (*badresult*). Of course, the content of the *badresult* will be total garbage and the app might crash on this line or later when it is trying to use the *badresult* elsewhere.
The problem is that it is very easy to make such mistakes in real life. The one I caught in my code looked like this:

```
message += port + "\n";
```

*(where message is a string type handling the result with its operator +=   function;  port is an int and \n is obviously a const char pointer).*

**Is there any way to disable this kind of behavior and trigger an error at compile time?**

I don't see any normal use case for adding char* to int and I would like a solution to prevent this kind of mistakes in my large code base.
When using classes, we can create private operators and use the explicit keyword to disable unneeded conversions/casts, however now we are talking about basic types (char* and int).

One solutions is to use clang as that has a flag to enable warning for this.
However I can't use clang, so I am seeking for a solution that triggers a compiler error (some kind of operator overload or mangling with some defines to prevent such constructs or any other idea).

Comment: There's a difference between a null-terminated byte string (like what `strval` is pointing to) and a `std::string` object. This also means there's a ***very*** big difference between C and C++, so please be careful about those language tags!

Comment: Also note that both `strval + ival` ***and*** `ival + strlval` are valid expressions, and means `&strval[ival]`. Which means your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) isn't complete nor verifiable, as the warning you ask about can't come from the code you show.

Comment: Adding an integer to a pointer is a fundamental part of the language; the same as indexing an array.  In both cases it is left to the responsibility of the the program to ensure that the result is valid.

Comment: C was designed for use by expert programmers. It gives you plenty of rope to hang yourself with, you just have to be careful. Modern compilers warn about many common mistakes, but they can't catch everything.

Comment: "very easy to make such mistakes in real life" - definitely it is hard to write such thing "in real life".

Comment: clang provides `-Wstring-plus-int` and `-Wstring-plus-char`, that would provide a warning for your use cases.

Comment: `const char *` is not a string type in C++. Use `std::string` instead

Comment: See [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62181).

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use clang. For the other comments: the problem has nothing to do with the string type, strlen or other string related things. Also I understand that adding integer to a pointer is valid in C/C++. But here we are adding a char* pointer to an integer and treating the result as a char* pointer which should worth a warning.

Comment: @Istvan: TBH, adding an integer value to a char pointer is something that I do frequently enough that such a warning would be inconvenient. The optimum for me would be a `char *` + character literal warning and possibly `char *`+ `char`.

Comment: "Unfortunately i can't use clang" - of course you can.  When g++ warnings are insufficient, I simply type 'clan' in front of the 'g++' ;)  Or are you saying you are not allowed to install it?  (Nobody need to know on your own computer, just be sure the last compile is g++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable this kind of behavior and trigger an error at compile time?

Not in general, because your code is very similar to the following, legitimate, code:

```
 int ival = 3;
 const char *strval = "abcd";
 const char *goodresult = ival + strval;
```

Here `goodresult` is pointing to the last letter `d` of `strval`.

BTW, on Linux, [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) is known to return a positive integer. So you could imagine:

```
 int ival = (getpid()>=0)?3:1000;
 const char *strval = "abcd";
 const char *goodresult = ival + strval;
```

which is morally the same as the previous example (so we humans know that `ival` is always 3). But teaching the compiler that `getpid()` does not return a negative value is tricky in practice (the return type `pid_t` of `getpid` is some *signed* integer, and has to be signed to be usable by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), which could give -1). And you could imagine more weird examples!

You want compile-time detection of [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (or more generally of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)), and in general that is equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) (it is an [unsolvable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)). So **it is impossible** in general.

Of course, one could claim that a clever compiler could warn for your particular case, but then there is a concern about what cases should be useful to warn.

You might try some [static source program analysis tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), perhaps [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) (with its recent Frama-C++ variant) - or some costly proprietary tools like [Coverity](https://scan.coverity.com/) and many others. These tools don't detect all errors statically and takes much more time to execute than an optimizing compiler.

You could (for example) write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to detect such mistakes (that means developing your own static source code analyzer). You'll spend months in writing it. Are you sure it is worth the effort?

> However I can't use clang,

Why? You could ask permission to use the clang static analyzer (or some other one), during development (not for production). If your manager refuses that, it becomes a management problem, not a technical one.

---

> I don't see any normal use case for adding char* to int

You need more imagination. Think of something like

```
puts("non-empty" + (isempty(x)?4:0));
```

Ok that is not very readable code, but it is legitimate. In the previous century, when memory was costly, some people used to code that way.

Today you'll code perhaps

```
if (isempty(x))
    puts("empty");
else
    puts("non-empty")
```

and the cute thing is that a clever compiler could probably [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) the later into the equivalent of former (according to the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)).

Comment: puts("non-empty" + (isempty(x)?4:0));   ...yes, this code example explains everything

Answer (score 1):

No way. It is valid syntax, and very useful in many cases.

Just think about you were to write `int b=a+10` but you wrote `int b=a+00` incorrectly, the compiler won't know it is an error by mistake.

However, you can consider to use C++ classes. Most C++ classes are well designed to prevent such obvious mistakes.

Comment: I understand that adding a pointer value to an int value is valid. But in real life such construct would be rarely needed, thus I think that we should get at least a compiler warning in this case.


Classes doesn't help me at all. I know that we can prevent unneeded type casts with classes using private members (private operators) and the explicit keyword.


However my problem is with the char* and int basic types. With other words, I would like to prevent somehow adding a char* (pointer) to an integer type.

Comment: For example in my code example, the message is my own string class. Obviously strings has a += const char* operator. I can't do anything from my class with this since the real problem is with the port + "\n" part of the code. Here we should have a warning, like "are you sure you want to add char* pointer value to int variable and treat the result as a char*?"

Answer (score 1):

In the first example in your question, really, compilers *should* issue a warning. Compilers can trivially see that the addition resolves to `8 + "x"` and clang does indeed optimise it to a constant. I see the fact it doesn't warn about this as a compiler bug. Although compilers are not required to warn about this, clang goes through great efforts to provide useful diagnostics, and it would be an improvement to diagnose this as well.

In the second example, as Matteo Italia pointed out, clang does already provide a warning option for this, enabled by default: `-Wstring-plus-int`. You can turn specific warnings into errors by using `-Werror=<warning-option>`, so in this case `-Werror=string-plus-int`.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use clang. Some general solution/workaround would be fine to trigger a compiler error in this case, or at least a warning.

Comment: @Istvan Unfortunately, for the general case, the problem is unsolvable: `message += port + "\n";` is perfectly valid C++ if `port` has the value `0` or `1`, and there is not and cannot be a standard way to reject standard C++ programs. Depending on the reason you cannot use clang, some other approach may be available, but there is no way to tell without more info.

Comment: port is not 0 or 1 here; it can be any number. message is my string class (which handles the result in it's operator += char* member.

Comment: Here we are adding a char* pointer to an integer and treating the result as a char* pointer which should worth a warning. So this is the problem:    const char *badresult = (int)ival + (const char*)strval;

I understand that this might be valid, but such mistake can be made very easily like in my example with message string and port int and a way to generate an error or warning would be very helpful.

Comment: @Istvan But the compiler cannot know that `port` is greater than `1`, so the compiler cannot reject the addition. Rejecting *any* addition of an integer to a `char *` pointer would have a lot of false positives. When you have a range of `char`s and want to iterate over them using a begin and end pointer, which is common in C++, you'll naturally increase the pointer by `1` each loop iteration.

Comment: "Rejecting any addition of an integer to a char * pointer"  ...

We are doing the exact inverse here by adding a char* pointer to an integer, which I think it is not so common (I don't see a use case for it). In addition we store a result in a char* which seems very unusual for me.

Comment: @Istvan Okay, but then you'd get no message for `message += "," + n;`. (Keep in mind that the selected overload of `operator+=` takes a parameter of type `const char *`.)